# Flutter How to print in debug consloe after killing the app

Tags: flutter, debugging, service, background

I know in flutter we can debug and print in the console even if the app is not running to test things in the background or other purposes , and i test it before but i forgot how to do it ,
it was a Command you write in turminal, so if anyone know please help me

Thanks for everyone

Comment: If you are using android studio then you have Logcat available for check

Comment: no im using vscode

Comment: Then i can't help with that if its android studio then you able to

Answer (score 8):

Can you try run on terminal ? :

```
flutter logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you print into the log using the `DebugPrint(String? , int?)` function
then you can enter `flutter logs` into the terminal (*Logcat* tab in the bottom bar if you Android Studio).

For easy use filter your log to your app package if you get logs from different apps.

Comment: correction* the function is debugPrint not DebugPrint from foundation.dart